# How many days will take to delete my WhatsApp account after uninstalling?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am very irritated with my friends and WhatsApp messages. I can't concentrate on my works. I am decided to uninstall my WhatsApp app from mobile. How many days will take to delete my WhatsApp account after uninstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to delete it separately... Unless they check active installations and remove accounts accordingly, the usual method of handling active user's is to require them to press "Delete Account" in Account settings prior to uninstalling.

An uninstall on android doesn't usually run anything, so it'd be hard for WhatsApp to remove the account whilst uninstalling ... Example, windows computers can run an extra code while uninstalling, it'll ask if you'd like to view the website or provide feedback on the uninstall.... Android should implement this one day, but for now it's seen as a method of stopping the app from being uninstalled, for example, your app could kill the uninstall process every time you attempt to uninstall it ... Making it a stubborn virus ( hypothetically ) ... Windows computers suffer with this problem and i don't think Android wants the same problems...

So because the application is sandboxed on uninstall, it can't remove your account from the server if you are uninstalling it .... This is extremely unhelpful for developing applications that modify system files and need to repair the files on an uninstall.. The app is killed on uninstall and can not restore the original files without including an uninstall button inside the application to handle everything prior to using uninstall ( make your own uninstaller ) ....

You need to remove, delete or disable your account on the WhatsApp Account settings prior to performing an uninstall... It's a limitation of Androids uninstalling process.

Alternatively WhatsApp could also check active installations and accounts associated with them, after an installation is missing, they can identify the account associated with it and remove it automatically... i believe this is what you theorized would happened, this usually isn't the method taken by any company, most want more user's and easier sign up processes, so it'd be counterproductive to remove accounts... it's easier for the end user to just reinstall the app and use the old logon information than to recreate an entire account, and it's better for the company to have more ( " Active " ) users.